# Como resultar objetos de mais de um array - PHP CURL

Tags: php, json, api, libcurl

Estou tentando fazer um echo de um objeto dentro de um array, já busquei em diversos tópicos mas não consegui nada que fosse similar ao que preciso.

Como não tenho ideia do que fazer a partir daqui, deixei o que tenhoa até agora

PHP

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://ssw.inf.br/api/trackingdanfe',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
    CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => '{
    "chave_nfe":     "3321081029676700024455001000756038128204****"
    }',
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
        'Content-Type: application/json',
    ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$obj = json_encode($response);

echo $obj;
```

retorno completo

```
"success": true,
    "message": "Documento localizado com sucesso",
    "documento": {
        "header": {
            "remetente": "****************************",
            "destinatario": "******************************",
            "nro_nf": "*****",
            "pedido": ""
        },
        "tracking": [
            {
                "data_hora": "2021-09-01T17:02:45",
                "dominio": "GEN",
                "filial": "BMA",
                "cidade": "BARRA MANSA / RJ",
                "ocorrencia": "MERCADORIA RECEBIDA PARA TRANSPORTE (89)",
                "descricao": "CT-e autorizado com 3 volumes e 28 Kg. Destino: PR/CURITIBA. Previsao de entrega: 06/09/21.",
                "tipo": "Informativo",
                "data_hora_efetiva": "2021-09-01T17:02:45",
                "nome_recebedor": "",
                "nro_doc_recebedor": ""
            },
            {
                "data_hora": "2021-09-02T13:10:33",
                "dominio": "GEN",
                "filial": "BMV",
                "cidade": "BARRA MANSA / RJ",
                "ocorrencia": "SAIDA DE UNIDADE (62)",
                "descricao": "Saida da unidade BARRA MANSA em 02/09/21, 13:10h. Previsao de chegada na unidade SAO PAULO em 02/09/21, 18:08h.",
                "tipo": "Informativo",
                "data_hora_efetiva": "2021-09-02T13:10:32",
                "nome_recebedor": "",
                "nro_doc_recebedor": ""
            },
            {
                "data_hora": "2021-09-02T18:48:41",
                "dominio": "GEN",
                "filial": "RTE",
                "cidade": "SAO PAULO / SP",
                "ocorrencia": "CHEGADA EM UNIDADE (64)",
                "descricao": "Chegada na unidade SAO PAULO em 02/09/21, 18:48h.",
                "tipo": "Informativo",
                "data_hora_efetiva": "2021-09-02T18:48:40",
                "nome_recebedor": "",
                "nro_doc_recebedor": ""
            },
            {
                "data_hora": "2021-09-03T04:27:04",
                "dominio": "GEN",
                "filial": "RTE",
                "cidade": "SAO PAULO / SP",
                "ocorrencia": "MERCADORIA RECEBIDA PARA TRANSPORTE (89)",
                "descricao": "MERCADORIA RECEBIDA PARA TRANSPORTE (SSW WebAPI Parceiro).",
                "tipo": "Informativo",
                "data_hora_efetiva": "2021-09-03T02:13:00",
                "nome_recebedor": "",
                "nro_doc_recebedor": ""
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

preciso retornar objetos dentro do

"tracking": [{

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você está usando `json_ENCODE` ao invés do `json_DECODE`. A resposta que você obtêm do cURL, nesse caso, é um JSON.

---

Você deve usar algo como:

```
//..

$response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);


$d = json_decode($response, true); 
foreach ($d['documento']['tracking'] as $_ => $v) {
    
    // Pegue os dados de cada 'tracking':
    printf("data: %s; dominio: %s <br>\n", $v['data_hora'], $v['dominio']);

}
```

O `$d['documento']['tracking']` é o que você quer. O `foreach` fará um loop em cada um dos `$d['documento']['tracking']`.

---

Para mais detalhes veja a documentação em https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php